# Read strings until end of lines

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

just to understand how to read correctly, how could i read the next text from file, if i want to read the diferent strings in each line. Each line can have different sizes (1st line could have 3 strings and 2nd line could have 100 strings)

```
2 //Number of lines
A AS BPST TRRER
B AS BP
```

I tried in my code something like this, but i dont know how to check if program it's in the end of line.

```
ifstream fich("thefile.txt");

fich >> aux; //Contain number of line

for(int i=0;i<aux;i++){  //For each line
   string line;
   getline(fich, line);

   char nt;    //First in line it's always a char
   fich >> nt;

   string aux;

   while(line != "\n"){   //This is wrong, what expression should i use to check?
      fich >> aux;
     //In each read i'll save the string in set
   }
}
```

So at the end, i want that set contains: `{{A,AS,BPST,TRRER} {B,AS,BP}}`

Thanks.

Comment: Use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the line.

Comment: Helpful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line/7868998#7868998 See option 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while(line != "\n"){   //This is wrong, what expression should i use to check?
> ```

Yes, because the `'\n'` was removed by the `getline()` function.

Using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) it is easy to parse an arbitrary number of words up to the end of the current `line`:

```
string aux;
std::istringstream iss(line);
while(iss >> aux) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Also note:

```
fich >> aux; //Contain number of line
```

will leave you with an empty line read with `std::getline()` because in this case the `'\n'` will be leftover from that operation (see [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin) for more detailed information).