# Need of cin.get() before getline(cin, string_name)

Tags: c++, string, cin

I have a simple program to output sum of 2 integers, double and concatenate 2 strings. Here is my code that works fine:

```
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    string s = "HackerRank ";  
    // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
    int i2;
    double d2;
    string s2;

    // Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
    cin>>i2;
    cin>>d2;
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, s2);

    // Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
    cout<<i+i2<<endl;

    // Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
    cout<< setprecision(1)<<fixed<<d+d2<<endl; 

    // Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
    // The 's' variable above should be printed first.
    cout<<s+s2;
    return 0;
}
```

However if I remove the statement `cin.get()` the input of the string `s2` doesn't take place. Why is this so??

I think this has something to do with the streams/input buffers and the inner coding of getline(cin, ). Moreover the program gives an error when I use `cin.getline()` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
cin.ignore();
```

then

```
getline(cin, s2);
cin.ignore();
```

This will flush the input stream.