# Taking multiple inputs with whitespaces using cin

Tags: c++, cin

I have a simple structure which stores details of a person whose values needs to be initialized through user input. The structure is as follows :

```
typedef struct {

        char name[20];
        int age;
        char address[50];
        char vehicle[10];
}Runner;
```

I am using `cin` to store the value of each `Runner` but wish to take the inputs (that may contain whitespace in between) using `enter key` after each value entered.

Below is the code :

```
Runner run1;

        cout << "Enter name age address vehicle (pressing enter at each instance)" << endl;
        cin >> run1.name >> run1.age >> run1.address >> run1.vehicle ;
```

It is quite evident that space separated values would be considered as two unique entries.

How do I skip the white-spaces and `cin` only after enter is pressed. Also if there is another approach to such situations, it would be great to know the same.

Comment: Use `std::getline` for each member of `Runner`.

Comment: @GillBates so I assume this could not be done in one line as asked in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the input may have whitespaces between them, you should use getline function.

```
cin.getline(run1.name,20);
cin.getline(run1.address,50);
cin.getline(run1.vehicle,10);
cin >> age
```

But if you want to take the value of age after taking the value of name, then you'll have to do something like this.

```
cin.getline(run1.name,20);
cin >> run1.age;
cin.getline(dummy,5);    //cin leaves a newline at the buffer. This line of code takes the newline from the buffer.
cin.getline(run1.address,50);
cin.getline(run1.vehicle,10);
```

Comment: Could you please explain more about the `dummy` thing that you have used in your code?

Comment: Yes. cin takes the input from the console. But leaves a newline '\n' in the buffer. And getline reads from the buffer untill a newline character has been found. So when you use getline immediately after a cin, the first cin leaves a newline and then the getline reads till the newline(so basically, getline reads an empty string). So if you delete the line cin.getline(dummy,5), the run1.adress will hold a empty string. So to remove the newline from the buffer, dummy takes the newline character, and run1.address had correct value.

Comment: For more read this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin

And the comment of Loki Askari

Answer (score 1):

```
cin.getline (name,20);
cin.getline (address,50);
cin.getline (vehicle,10);
cin >> age;
```