# How to accept a vector of strings where strings have spaces in them

Tags: c++, string, vector

My code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int s;
    cin>>s;
    vector<string> v(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        getline(cin,v[i]);
    }
    cout<<v[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to accept an array of strings where strings have spaces in them. The above program doesn't work as it terminates before the loop ends and instead of the second string in the vector `v[1]` it prints first `v[0]` no matter what the value of `int s` is.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I correctly accept an array of strings with spaces?

Comment: You are printing v[1], not v[i]

Comment: @JerryCoffin He declares the used namespace above main

Comment: It *does*  print `v[1]`, it's just that `v[1]` is not the string you expect it to be.

Comment: @stark That statement is outside the loop, `i` is not defined there. Perhaps OP just wants to print the 2nd word.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin

Comment: @stark I am using just for testing purpose. But it still doesn't display `v[1]`, displays `v[0]` and the loop runs one time less than it actually should. For example if s=2 loop runs once and displays `v[0]`, if `s=3` loop runs twice and still displays` v[0]`

Comment: Your first getline returns the empty line after reading s

Comment: @GameDev90 No, `v[0]` is the empty string. [Illustration](http://ideone.com/2MPlNM).

Answer (score 0):

Use `cin.ignore(INTEGER_MAX, '\n');` before each `getline` statement to clear the cin buffer.