# How to remove consonants from a string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdstring, erase

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    while(n--)
    {
        string str;
        char a[] = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
        getline(cin, str);

        for(int i=0 ;i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                if(str[i]==a[j])
                {
                    cout << str[i];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test cases are :

```
HmlMqPhBfaVokhR 
wdTSFuI 
IvfHOSNv
```

I am not removing anything but I am printing only vowels. But, some test cases didn't pass. Maybe this code doesn't work on multiple test cases.

Comment: a) you are not removing anything from the string b) what are the test cases? c) you should include `<string>` not `<string.h>`

Comment: What's the description and what's the problem?

Comment: One bug is, you need to `ignore()` after  `cin>>n;`, otherwise `getline(cin, str);`, will not get anything. and this is not what you should do : `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: Test cases are :
HmlMqPhBfaVokhR
wdTSFuI IvfHOSNv

I updated <string.h> to <string> but problem is not solved.
I am not removing anything but I am printing only vowels.

Comment: @PriyamRajvanshi Edit your question with test cases, not in comments.

Comment: btw in general your [mcve] is more selfcontained if you put the input hardcoded in the code instead of using user input, on the other hand it might be that the bug is in how you take the user input, and on the other other hand you better seperate input and logic anyhow (ie make a function `remove_consonants` that takes a `string` as parameter and can be tested independent of where that string is coming from)

Comment: @JeJo can you provide me the code please?

Comment: Check this out [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739937/1332041)

Comment: Now do you want to really remove the vowels or do you just want to print out the input without them?

Comment: You need to show the tests (possibly only the failing tests).  Without that, your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Try this *[for proper console in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)* :

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();   // fix
    /* remaining code */
    return 0;
}
```

---

### > To find the vowels in a string

On way of finding the vowels in a *string* is using a `std::binary_search` each character of the given string in a vowel table.

1. Make a sorted *array of `char`* s of all *vowels*(i.e. *vowels array*).
2. For each `char` of the input string, [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) in the
   *vowels array*.
3. If `std::binary_search` returns `true`(meaning the `char` is an vowel), print the `char` of the string.

Following is the example code! **([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/2trIql))**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::for_each, std::binary_search, std::sort
#include <array>     // std::array

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> a{ 'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U' };
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // need sorted array for std::binary_search

    const std::string str{ "HmlMqPhBfaVokhR wdTSFuI IvfHOSNv" };
    std::for_each(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [&](const char str_char)
    {
        if (std::binary_search(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), str_char))
            std::cout << str_char << " ";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
a o u I I O
```

---

### > To remove the vowels from a string

Use *[erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)* as follows(**till [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)<sup>†</sup>**).

1. Make a sorted *array of `char`* s of all *vowels*(i.e. *vowels array*).
2. Using [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), collect the iterators pointing to the characters, which are vowels. A lambda function can be used as the predicate for `std::remove_if`, where the [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) is used to check the `char` in the string exists in the *vowels array*.
3. Using [`std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), erase all the collected characters(i.e. vowels) from the string.

Following is an example code! **([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/zi-su0))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::sort, std::binary_search, std::remove_if
#include <array>     // std::array

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> a{ 'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U' };
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // need sorted array for std::binary_search

    std::string str{ "Hello World" };
    // lambda(predicate) to check the `char` in the string exist in vowels array
    const auto predicate = [&a](const char str_char) -> bool { 
        return std::binary_search(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), str_char);
    };
    // collect the vowels
    const auto vowelsToRemove = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), predicate);
    // erase the collected vowels using std::string::erase
    str.erase(vowelsToRemove, str.end());

    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Hll Wrld
```

**<sup>†</sup>** Since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), one can use [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2) for this, which would be *[less error prone than the the above one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859485/does-c-standard-library-provide-more-compact-and-generalized-version-of-the-er)*. **([See online live using *GCC 9.2*](https://godbolt.org/z/x5gnx7))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    // std::string, std::erase_if
#include <array>     // std::array

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> a{ 'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U' };
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // need sorted array for std::binary_search

    std::string str{ "Hello World" };
    // lambda(predicate) to check the `char` in the string exist in vowels array
    const auto predicate = [&a](const char str_char) -> bool { 
        return std::binary_search(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), str_char);
    };

    std::erase_if(str, predicate); // simply erase

    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

### > To remove the consonants from a string

To remove the consonants from the given string, in the above `predicate` negate the result of `std::binary_search`. **([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/DFNtHf))**

```
const auto predicate = [&a](const char str_char) -> bool { 
    return !std::binary_search(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), str_char);
    //     ^^ --> negate the return
};
```

---

As side notes,

- Avoid the `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` Read more: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
- Do not practice with `using namespace std;` Read more: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: How do you know what “ascending order” is for the vector of characters? And how do you know that a binary search will be faster than a linear search for such a short list of characters?

Comment: @PeteBecker do you agree **O(log10)** < **O(10)** ? if so binary search is better always. However, for a small array we can also do liner look ups, which in end effects will not be a big performance difference.

Comment: If input is small enough, the sorting overhead even might consume all of the little benefit that possibly yet remains... Suppose the problem is just too simple for such an elaborate approach (but I like it...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: regarding `std::sort()`, its true what you said. He could also use the sort before the loop, so that each time the sorting can be avoided. However, I just generalized the situation, which will be applicable to other characters which are not vowels. Furthermore, binary search is my habit. However, I found `strchr` also a good approach as the array is small.

Comment: @JeJo -- binary search is better for **large inputs**. Asymptotic complexity is about **asymptotes**; it is not an absolute measure of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `std::getline` problem already answered:

```
for(int i=0 ;i<str.length(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        if(str[i] == a[j])
        {
            // this is the one you do NOT want to print...
            // cout<<str[i];
            // skip instead:
            goto SKIP;
        }
    }
    std::cout << str[i]; // output the one NOT skipped...
    SKIP: (void)0;
}
```

OK, don't want to start any discussion about usage of `goto`, there are many ways to avoid it, e. g. by packing the inner for loop into a separate (inline) function. You can have it easier, though, as there already exists such a function; code gets even easier with a range-based for loop:

```
for(auto c : str)
{
    if(!strchr("aeiouAEIOU", c))
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

`strchr` (from cstring) returns a pointer to the first character in the string equal to the reference character - or nullptr if not found...

To really *remove* the vowels from the string in a modern C++ way, consider this:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(
        str.begin(), str.end(),
        [](char c) { return strchr("aeiouAEIOU", c) != nullptr; }
    ), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably should looks like (please see comments inline):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

    int n;
    cin>>n; // assume this stands for line count

    while(n-- >= 0)
    {
        string str, result;
        getline(cin, str);

        for(int i=0 ;i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (vowels.find(str[i]) != std::string::npos)
                result += str[i];   // add character to result if it is not consonant
        }
        cout<<result<<"\n"; // print result
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn’t fix the problem. All it does is complexity the code; it produces exactly the same output.

Comment: @PeteBecker OP didn't actually explain the issue well. I figured out the line count is one less than it should be. Not sure if that is the problem.