# Does C++ standard library provide more compact and generalized version of the erase–remove idiom?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, c++20, erase-remove-idiom

We can erase one element/ entry from a container by the popular [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).
However,  many of us would have encountered some problems while applying this idiom:

- one can easily get into the pitfall of **typos** like

  ```
  c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred));
  //                                             , c.end() //---> missing here
  ```

  or

  ```
  c.erase((std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), pred), c.end()))
  //      ^^                                               ^^
  // extra () makes it pass only c.end() to the c.erase
  ```
- It even follows the **wrong semantics** for containers like
  `std::list` by not selecting its own member
  [`std::list::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove)
  for the idiom.
- Thirdly, using `std::remove_if` [**does not work for associative
  containers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap).

---

**Do we have anything generalized and less typo-prone** than `std::erase-std::remove_if` or something like `std::erase_if` within the scope of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), or will there be such a utility in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Not in the scope of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), but [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) onwards!

**Yes**. The proposal of consistent container erasure has been mentioned in [n4009 paper](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4009.txt) and finally adopted in [C++20 standard as **`std::erase_if`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2#Uniform_container_erasure) which is **a non-member function for each containers**.

This ensures a uniform container erasure semantics for `std::basic_string` and [all standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), except `std::array`(as it has the fixed-size).

This means that the boilerplate code

```
container.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        container.begin(), container.end(),
        [](const auto& element) ->bool { return /* condition */; }),
    vec.end());
```

will simply melt down to a **generalized form** of

```
std::erase_if(container, [](const auto& element) ->bool { return /* condition */; });
```

Secondly, this uniform syntax selects **the proper semantics for each container**. This means

- For sequence containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase2) and for
  [`std::std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2), it will be equivalent to

  ```
  container.erase(
         std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), unaryPredicate)
         , container.end()
  );
  ```
- For sequence containers [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase2) and [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2), it will
  be equivalent to

  ```
  container.remove_if(unaryPredicate);
  ```
- For ordered associative containers(i.e. [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase_if), [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if),
  [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase_if) and [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase_if)) and unordered associative
  containers(i.e. [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase_if), [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if),
  [`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/erase_if) and [`std::unordered_multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/erase_if)), the
  `std::erase_if` is equivalent to

  ```
  for (auto i = container.begin(), last = container.end(); i != last; ) 
  {
    if (unaryPredicate(*i)) 
    {
      i = container.erase(i);
    }
    else
    {
      ++i;
    }
  }
  ```

---

In addition to that, the standard also added **`std::erase` for sequence containers** of the form

```
std::erase(container, value_to_be_removed);
```

Comment: How do I extend this for my own containers? Will my own `erase_if(...)` be found by ADL?

Comment: @Justin if I understood correctly, defining a  non-member `erase_if(...)` for the own container wouldn't be enough? maybe putting the scope of `std::` will be adding to namespace std. But later part I am not sure.

Comment: Indeed, from the paper, this utility is specified for each standard container and doesn't use ADL. As adding a custom overload to `std` is not allowed, the way to customize this for your own containers would be to define your own separate `erase_if` in your own namespace, which could forward on to `std::erase_if` or your own containers'.

Comment: @Justin No ADL means that an unqualified call, like  `{ using std::erase_if; erase_if(...); }`, won't help to find ones own non-member `erase_if`, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You could write that, and it would find your own `erase_if` (provided it can be found by ADL, such as if it is defined in the same namespace as your container).

Comment: Whatever for do you force the lambdas to have return-type `bool`?

Comment: @Deduplicator It is a matter of taste. I would say. being explicit `ret`in *[ captures ] ( params ) -> ret { body }* (about lambdas), not a bad practice, IMHO.