# A C++ way to replace all periods in a string with a single line of code?

Tags: c++, string, replaceall

A given string needs to be modified so that there are no periods. The rest of the string remains intact.

I thought of using an iterative approach and using string::erase.
In java, I could have easily accomplished it with replaceAll function.
Thinking along those lines a developer published a solution :

```
        temp.erase(remove(temp.begin(),temp.end(),'.'),temp.end());
```

The line of code works perfectly. However I failed to understand how it works. As far as my understanding goes the erase function deletes all characters in a range.
The remove function is returning the iterator to the point after removing the periods, and then the erase function is erasing from that point. I'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: "Any ideas" about what, exactly?  What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C++ standard library provide more compact and generalized version of the erase–remove idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859485/does-c-standard-library-provide-more-compact-and-generalized-version-of-the-er)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to get confused but the remove function is **not** removing all the periods.

Suppose before `remove` your string was `"a.b.c."` then after `remove` it would be `"abc..."`. What the erase method is doing is erasing the periods that are now at the end of the string.

Now it's a reasonable question to ask why `remove` behaves this way, but think about what `remove` has, it only has a pair of iterators. Iterators cannot be used to remove items from a container, an iterator does not give you access to the container that it refers to. So `remove` (and other similar functions) cannot delete anything from a container. All they can do is rearrange the order so that some later code can easily do the actual deleting.

There's a name for this idiom but it escapes me at the moment.

Comment: oh so the erase is deleting the last three dots after remove is altering the string? Great! That explains!

Comment: After `remove` the string would most likely be "abc.c." since it moves good elements to the beginning. It's more like a move-left-if than a partition operation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes good point. Formerly I think the tail portion of the container is unspecified.

Comment: @InferTech You got it, this is the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: The erase/remove idiom is also very efficient. It's just a swap for each match. Erasing elements one at a time is slow because all the elements after each one have to be moved down for each item erased. So even w/o the iterator issue, this would be a poor approach.

Comment: @doug, it's not exactly as "swap" but rather a "move to end" which is essentially a `memmov` of the rest of the string (or container) from the from the position after current to current while placing the current at the end.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, duh, you're right. That suggests the erase/remove idiom isn't all that efficient if there are lots of matches. It may be be faster to do a conditional copy. For instance, to a preallocated vector. I've been coding as if the erase/remove idiom was pretty optimal. For vectors even with move capability that aren't POD this could be much slower than a selected copy. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @doug it's as efficient as it can be. You really have 2-options. Either `memmov` the rest of the string forward overwriting the character and moving the character to the end, or build a temporary container without character keeping count and put that many at the end. I haven't checked the libc++ source, but either would be fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I'd bet that `std::copy_if` into another, size initialized, container would be faster. It should eliminate a lot of unnecessary moves in sets with a reasonable percentage of matches. I haven't benchmarked it but will consider this the next time I run across the need.

Comment: I bet you are right, I was just thinking what the most basic underlying call would be. That's why I mentioned I had not looked at the source yet. Whether it is a `std::copy_if` or a `while (strchr (str.c_str(), c)` both would probably optimize to essentially the same assembly code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Nothing is "moved to the end" when calling [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). It's not a partition operation. Each good element to be kept is moved to the left at most once. The elements after the new logical end have unspecified values.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thank you. As noted multiple times I did not consult libstdc++. But question, if you have `A.B.C.` and call `std::remove` and each good element to be kept is move to the left at most *once*, how do you end up with `ABC...`? If each is moved to the left only once, are you not left with `AB.C..`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I should have been clearer. Each element is only moved a single time but it can jump multiple places to the left in that single move. If you start with `A.B.C.` the result should be `ABC.C.`, the `C` moved two slots to the left but was only **touched** once. That's why the algorithm is so efficient.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ok, thank you, that lets all the gears fit together upstairs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

`std::remove` acts on a range. A range is a pair of iterators denoting its `begin` and `end`, respectively.

`std::string::erase`, or any containers `erase`, acts on a `string` (/container).

Removing an element from a range can be thought of as returning a new range. For example you remove an element from a range by placing it at the `end` and the new range is from `begin` till `end-1`.

Erasing an element from a container is something different. The container owns the element and is responsible for actually "erasing" the element.

In summary: You start will all elements in the range made up by `temp.begin()` till `temp.end()` passed to `std::remove` which returns you the `end` of the new range (after shuffling the elements) and finally `std::string::erase` shrinks the `string` to contain only that new range of characters.