# Printing the searched line

Tags: c++, search, data-structures

I want to search for a name from a list of names and if its found I should return the whole info of that person else not found. I dont know why my code is not working. I can print the info of the person, eg:

Input:

```
3
Steve 9812761810 017
Wayne 8299915781 102
Ronnie 9161462903 120
Wayne
```

Output:

```
Wayne 8299915781 102
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name[100];
  long long number[100];
  int year[100], i, n, check = 0;
  string inp;
  cin >> n;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> name[i] >> number[i] >> year[i];
  }
  cin >> inp;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (inp == name[i]) {
      check = 1;
    }
  }
  if (check == 0)
    cout << "Info Not found";
  else
    cout << "The Entered Name is found";
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    cout << name[i] << number[i] << year[i];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" look like?  A compiler error?  Some unexpected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading an integer from the input stream, you should use `cin.ignore();` before reading any strings from the input stream.

`cin.ignore();` ignores the "new line" character.

Your modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name[100];
  long long number[100];
  int year[100], i, n, check = 0;
  string inp;
  cin >> n;
  cin.ignore();
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> name[i] >> number[i] >> year[i];
    cin.ignore();
  }
  cin >> inp;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (inp == name[i]) {
      check = 1;
    }
  }
  if (check == 0)
    cout << "Info Not found";
  else
    cout << "The Entered Name is found";
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    cout << name[i] << number[i] << year[i];
  return 0;
}
```

Read more here: [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin)

Comment: `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace **including line breaks**, unless `std::noskipws` is used.  What you say would be true if the OP were reading values any other way, like `std::getline()`, `std::cin.get()`, etc, but since all reading in the OP's code is being done using `operator>>` only, calling `cin.ignore()` should not matter. Also, your code is making the same mistake the OP's code is making regarding writing out the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the program, you are ignoring the value of `check` and just printing everything in your list regardless of whether the entered name was actually found or not.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name[100];
    long long number[100];
    int year[100], i, n, idx = -1;
    string inp;

    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> name[i] >> number[i] >> year[i];
    }

    cin >> inp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (inp == name[i]) {
            idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (idx == -1)
        cout << "Info Not found";
    else {
        cout << "The Entered Name is found: ";
        cout << name[idx] << " " << number[idx] << " " << year[idx];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might also consider using a `struct` to organize your data better, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct myData {
    string name;
    long long number;
    int year;
};

istream& operator>>(istream &is, myData &data) {
    is >> data.name >> data.number >> data.year;
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const myData &data) {
    os << data.name << " " << data.number << " " << data.year;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    myData data[100];
    int i, n, idx = -1;
    string inp;

    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> data[i];
    }

    cin >> inp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (inp == data[i].name) {
            idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (idx == -1)
        cout << "Info Not found";
    else
        cout << "The Entered Name is found: " << data[idx];

    return 0;
}
```