# getline() in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

Why doesn't the getline function takes input here ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned n {}, m {};
    cin >> n >> m;

    string set;
    getline(cin, set);
    cout<<set<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT PROVIDED:

```
1 5
Hello World
```

OUPUT DISPLAYED:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::getline(istream&,std::string&)` doesn't work the same way `cin>>var` works.
When you use `cin>>var` the right input is absorbed to the var correctly and if there is a space before it it is ignored but `std::getline` doesn't ignore the space, so we used `std::cin.ignore()` to ignore the `\n`. If you don't ignore it, the string will encouter it and then won't absorb your line because `std::getline()` stops on encountering  a `\n`.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        unsigned n {}, m {};
        cin >> n >> m;

        string set;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, set);
        cout<<set<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain @anonymous ??