# The program is ignoring the username and only allowing me to type password?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class acc_cr{
protected:
  string username;
  string password;
  int i = 0;
public:
  void create(){
    fstream fout;

    //new username:
    cout<<"Enter Your New Username:\n";
    while(i == 0){
      getline(cin,username);

      stringstream check(username);
      string intermediate;

      // Tokenizing w.r.t. space ' '
      //Extracting the username up to first space
      getline(check, intermediate,' ');

      //Checking if anything is there after first space
      if(getline(check, intermediate,' ')){
        cout<<"Invalid Username-Contains Spaces!\nTry Another Username:\n";
      }

      //checking if this username already exists:
      else if(fstream(username)){
        cout<<"Username Already Exists!\nTry Another Username:\n";
      }
      else{
        fout.open(username,ios::out);//creating new file to store contents
        break;//breaking loop
      }
    }

    //new password:
    cout<<"Enter Your New Password:\n";
    while(i == 0){
      getline(cin,password);

      //Extracting
      stringstream pass(password);
      string a_ps;
      getline(pass,a_ps,' ');

      //checking whether password contains spaces:
      if(getline(pass,a_ps,' ')){
        cout<<"Invalid Password - Constains Spaces\nTry Another Password\n";
      }
      else{
        break;//breaking loop
      }
    }

    //inserting data into csv file:
    fout<<username<<","
        <<password<<"\n";
  }
};
```

The purpose of this code is to ask for a username and  password and create a csv file in which it will store these details and also the name of the csv file is same as username as you can see it in the code....but the problem here is it is not asking the username but rather only asking for password only....the output is like this:

```
Enter your username!
Enter Your Password!
|(blinker)//this is where i am only abled to type
```

it is only all allowing me to type password and not username.....i don't know why...

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. For example a call to `std::cin >>` could explain what you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin

Comment: Nowhere I've found "Enter your username!" & "Enter Your Password!" in the code. Didn't you mean: "Enter your new username"?

Comment: What is the purpose of `while(i == 0)`, should it be `while (true)` instead (and get rid of `i`?

Comment: yes i mean "Enter Your Username"

Comment: @Evg it is still not working

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How can we find the problem if we don't know the value of `i` when you call `create`? Is the input stream empty before you call `create`? Probably there are some line breaks that are read in `getline(cin,username);`.

Comment: thomas the value of i is 0 you can see it in the top of the code....i am bit confused...thats why i uploaded the whole code so that you can give me appropriate suggestion

Comment: The value of `i` is 0 when you create the object. But I can't see what happens after you create the object and before you call `create`. You didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should check @idclev463035818's first comment. Without [mcve] we can't say for sure but it's probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When entering the name using the extract operator >>, the entry process stops at the first blank space. Unprocessed characters remain in the input buffer (
The buffer is a block of memory where keyboard input (or another sequence, such as a file) is temporarily stored.). This includes the newline character '' n 'that was entered from the keyboard after the data.
If you then perform a getline () operation, it will process everything down to the first character again
line. The new line itself is dropped. So you will get the remains of the previous entry, which is an empty line. That's why I recommend you better use cin, just modifying the getline by cin your problem would be solved

```
class acc_cr{
protected:
  string username;
  string password;
  int i = 0;
public:
  void create(){
    fstream fout;

    //new username:
    cout<<"Enter Your New Username:\n";
    while(i == 0){
      cin>>username;

      stringstream check(username);
      string intermediate;

      // Tokenizing w.r.t. space ' '
      //Extracting the username up to first space
      getline(check, intermediate,' ');

      //Checking if anything is there after first space
      if(getline(check, intermediate,' ')){
        cout<<"Invalid Username-Contains Spaces!\nTry Another Username:\n";
      }

      //checking if this username already exists:
      else if(fstream(username)){
        cout<<"Username Already Exists!\nTry Another Username:\n";
      }
      else{
        fout.open(username,ios::out);//creating new file to store contents
        break;//breaking loop
      }
    }

    //new password:
    cout<<"Enter Your New Password:\n";
    while(i == 0){
      cin>>password;

      //Extracting
      stringstream pass(password);
      string a_ps;
      getline(pass,a_ps,' ');

      //checking whether password contains spaces:
      if(getline(pass,a_ps,' ')){
        cout<<"Invalid Password - Constains Spaces\nTry Another Password\n";
      }
      else{
        break;//breaking loop
      }
    }

    //inserting data into csv file:
    fout<<username<<","
        <<password<<"\n";
  }
};
```