# Error No instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, getline

I've searched this website and I have tried most things and they all don't work If anyone knows what I am doing wrong please help, This is my code.

```
 string getlinetest;
 cout << "What is the string?" << endl;
 cin >> getlinetest;
 getline(cin >> getlinetest);
 cout << getlinetest << endl;
```

Comment: Can you tell what is happening in the 4th line? What dou want to pass to getline? Maybe you can figure it out, on yourself

Comment: Either `cin>>getline;` or `getline(cin, getlinetest);`. Beware of [mixing these two options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).

Comment: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is not used as you are trying to use it. (I think you just made a typo by using `>>` instead of `,`.)

You need to call it like this:

```cpp
std::string getlinetest;
std::cout << "What is the string?" << std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin, getlinetest);
std::cout << getlinetest << std::endl;
```

***PS:***

And I don't get any sense behind using `cin >> getlinetest;` before using `getline`. If you want to remove preceding whitespaces, then you probably need to use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead of putting a `cin` statement before.

Check out these threads:

1. [Using getline(cin, s) after cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin)
2. [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)
3. [cin and getline skipping input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input)