# My C++ program crashed whenever I try to read the string

Tags: c++, string, struct

Here my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 100

struct person{
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

void entry(struct person *info){
  std::getline(std::cin, info->name);
  std::cin >> info->age;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct person roster[SIZE];
  int n; // number of people in the roster:
  std::cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    entry(&roster[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am learning how to use "struct" in c++ and in this program, I created a roster includes name and age, but the program crashed whenever I try to read the string "name". Can you help me? Thank you, I stuck at this for days.

P.s: I am learning c++ with a C-book, so my code might contain C-ism.

Comment: "I am learning c++ with a C-book" -- please don't. They are very different languages

Comment: Can you also show the input that you provide to your program? It might help understand where exactly, your program crashes.

Comment: You say <<but the program crashed whenever I try to read the string "name">>.

What is your input?

For example, is it something like: "2<new line>frank<new line>10<new line>johnni<new line>12"?

There is nothing obviously wrong with your program, so you need to provide the text you type into the prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't mind the prints to user I've introduced here. The execution flow is just so much more clear with them.

So, you should look toward the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 100

struct person{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

void entry(struct person *info){
    std::cout << "Enter name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, info->name);
    std::cout << "\nAge: ";
    std::cin >> info->age;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    person roster[SIZE];
    int n; // number of people in the roster:
    std::cout << "Number of people in roster: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        entry(&roster[i]);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Number of people in roster: 3
Enter name: Foo
Age: 22

Enter name: Bar
Age: 33

Enter name: Baz
Age: 44
```

The main issue you were having is of a complex nature, the roots of which are in the `getline()` behavior. I would suggest you to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) for more elaboration.

For what is `std::cin.ignore()` check the [documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/). And on when and how to use it, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

After declaring a `struct`, to declare the variable, you simply do the same way when declaring an `int` or `double`:

```
(struct) <struct_name> <variable_name> = <value>;
```

And that's where C and C++ is different. In C++, the struct keyword is optional before in declaration of a variable. In C, it is mandatory. That's why

> I am learning c++ with a C-book

is a huge no. While some of their syntaxes are similar, the rest are vastly different. If you are learning C++, please find the corresponding course/book/video. They're abundance.

For [the `getline()` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin), you can include `cin.ignore()` for the program to ignore the rest of the character of that line and go to a new line.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 100

struct person{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

void entry(person *info){
    std::cin.ignore(); //ignores every character until next line
    std::getline(std::cin, info->name);
    std::cin >> info->age;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    person roster[SIZE];
    int n; // number of people in the roster:
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        entry(&roster[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        person cur = roster[i];
        std::cout << cur.name << " " << cur.age << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
2
Beck
8
John Doe
25
Beck 8
John Doe 25
```

Comment: @stuff_and_stuff remember, get an actual C++ book to code properly in C++ 

Comment: I appreciate that